# Function to perform insert based on form data and passed values

Tags: php, html

short(est) version: I created a simple CMS that allows the user to choose from 4 templates. Each template has different panel types. For this example I'm showing a full page template which only has one full page panel.

Basically, the panel offers up an instance of TinyMCE to allow the user to create text/image content for the panel.

The flow is:
Content ->(assigned to)->Panel->(assigned to)->Page->(assigned to)->display

So in this case, the user selects a link which passes a value through the URL, in this case the value is 1. This tells templates.php to include fullWidth.php

So templates.php has a save form with a submit button, and the loaded fullWidth.php file has the panel template which gives us the number for panel type as well as the content in a textarea.

My problem is, I need to fully realize a function that saves a page (which by proxy saves records for content and panels as well)

So with the code below, I would be inserting into 3 different tables basically, but the `panels` table is inserting foreign keys; the IDs of the newly created `pages` entry as well as the newly inserted `content` entry.

I know the majority of this is just inserting some form values into the database but I have 2 main hurdles here:

1. How to insert values that aren't in the form such as the content and panel_type ID from fullwidth.php as well as the passed in $value in templates.php
2. How to create a function that does the main inserting with the ability to grab 2 different IDs used as foreign keys for panels.

For this example with the code I'm posting (assuming the user is selecting the hard coded `<options>` I'm using below), I would insert:

saveContentPage.php

```
//This is complete pseudo code, I'm not sure how the syntax would change for the different types
$title= $_POST['$title'];
$pageType= $_POST['$value'];
$displayId = $_POST['#areaSelect'];
$start_time = now();
$end_time = $_POST['#datePicker'];
$slide_order = $_POST['#orderSet'];
$duration = $_POST['#durationSet'];

$sql="INSERT INTO pages(title, page_type_id, display_id, start_time, end_time, slide_order, duration) 
        VALUES ('$title','$pageType','$displayId','$start_time','$end_time','$slide_order','$duration')";

//Here I need to pass the content from the included fullwidth.php to get the textarea content and the panel_type_id
$content = $_POST['textArea']

$sql = "INSERT INTO content(content)
        Values('$content')";

if(#id = FullPage){
$panel_type = 1;
}

$sql = INSERT INTO panels (panel_type_id, page_id, cont_id)
        VALUES ('$panel_type', /*ID that was created from 'pages' insert*/, /*ID that was created from 'content' INSERT*/)
```

How can I create a function that performs the necessary insert(s)?

Code:

templates.php

```
    <!-- check GET 'value' -->
    <?php $value = isset($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : 1;?>

    <!-- If value is 1 then load the full page template class -->
    <?php if($value == 1){?>
    <?php include 'class/fullWidth.php'?>

    <!-- Submit button that links to modal with a 'save page' form inside -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="savePageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="savePageLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="savePageLabel">Page Details:</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button> 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- this is the URL value i.e. templates.php?value=1 and should insert into pages.page_type_id -->
                        <label>Page Type: <?php echo $value;?></label>
                        </br>

                        <!-- This is page title, should map to pages.title -->
                        <label for="addTitle">Page Title:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="addTitle">
                        </input>

                        <!-- This shows the displays, will save the ID of the selected option to pages.display_id -->
                        <label for="areaSelect">Select An Area</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="areaSelect">

                            <option>4</option>


                        </select>

                        <!-- Input for seconds, will save to pages.duration -->
                        <label for="durationSet">Set A Duration (in seconds)</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="durationSet">
                        </input>

                        <!-- User selects order of slide -->
                        <label for="orderSet">Set Slide Order</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="orderSet">
                            <option>3</option>
                        </select>

                        <!-- This datepicker allows user to pick a date and time, will save as TIMESTAMP to pages.end_time -->
                        <label for="expirationSelect">Set Expiration Date/Time</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="datepick input-group date" id="datetimepicker" data-target-input="nearest">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

fullwidth.php

```
    <!-- This file is loaded based on page type ($value) from templates.php
        It loads an HTML template which has a main div houseing the panel_type and it has
        a textarea that houses the content -->

    <div class="row middle">
        <div class="col-lg-12 fullWidth">
            <!-- This Div ID is 1 which maps to the panel_type of this div, so upon saving It should insert to panels.panel_type_id a value of 1 -->
            <div class="fullContent" id="fullPage" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">
                <!-- THis is simply a modal that givees the user an interface to use TinyMCE in order to fill the content of mytextarea3 -->
                <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="fullModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fullLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title" id="fullModal">Content Library:</h5>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h3>Create your own content</h3>
                                <form id="form-data3" method="post">
                                    <!-- This is the text area that should be saved to content.content -->
                                  <textarea id="mytextarea3"></textarea>
                                  <input type="submit" value="Get Data">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can pass extra values with a form using `<input type="hidden" .. >`

Comment: So that should solve one of my problems, if I use hidden inputs for things like the panel_id as well as the $value passed from the URL right?